# How do I right-click -> Save in Microsoft's Edge browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge

In Chrome, you can right-click and see an option to 'Save Link As', but it doesn't appear the same way in Edge.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: You can't, as of today.

Currently there is no mechanism to right click on a link and “save as” or “save target as.” It's on the radar, and you can make [additional requests on User Voice](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/285214-microsoft-edge/suggestions/9111460--save-target-as-and-a-confirmation-on-download).

Comment: I clarified above. I should have said "radar" and not "road map".

Comment: That link is now restricted @DaveVoyles

Comment: Looks like they recently changed it. No idea.

Comment: Maybe you mean the following link regarding the topic: **Save Target in MS Edge** [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/save-target-in-ms-edge](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/save-target-in-ms-edge/efc653f4-c9e5-4c4b-b548-a9a712225a79)