# Microsoft Edge plays audio files that used to be downloads

Tags: html, audio, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have a website with many links like this one:

```
<a href="http://www.biblical-thinking.org/DOC-1Th/audio/1Thess140615.mp3">(Download Audio)</a>
```

My visitors are used to clicking on that link and downloading the audio file.

With the installation of Windows 10 and Microsoft Edge, the behavior now is to immediately play the file.  I would like to find out how to manage this so that it still downloads as before.  Even if it is just a setting that I need to tell people about; most of my visitors will not want to play the file immediately but to save it for later.

Comment: Use the `download=""` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for that quick response.  I will keep it in mind for later; I did try it, but the download attribute is new and is not yet supported by some browsers (including, apparently, MS Edge).  I have a couple of down votes on this; I don't know if it is being considered a stupid question or just in the wrong place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use Content-disposition for force a file to download to the hard drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

There the ability to download files from within Edge does not currently exist, but it is on the roadmap.

I go into some [detail here, in another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976394/how-do-i-right-click-save-in-microsofts-edge-browser)